# pure grid list floating dynamic height doesn't work

Tags: html, css

so i want to archive list with dynamic height so it starts the second line at the left side of the page. Like bellow:

```
||  ||  ||   ||
    ||

||  ||  ||   ||
```

If i use `display: inline-block; vertical-align:top` this works, but If i put each block 25%, it only shows 3 blocks on one line. 
So I use `float:left` Then it shows 4 blocks on one line, as supposed to. But then everything breaks apart.

```
 ||  ||  ||   ||
     ||

         ||   ||
||   ||
```

I tried it with just plain html/css everything works, so i guess its something with pure. Can anybody help ?

Code:

```
<ul>
<li class="pure-u-md-6-24">1Teskts<br/>Teksts</li>
<li class="pure-u-md-6-24">2Teskts<br/>TekstTeskts<br/>TekstsTeskts<br/>TekstsTeskts<br/>Tekstss</li>
<li class="pure-u-md-6-24">3Teskts<br/>Teksts</li>
<li class="pure-u-md-6-24">4Teskts<br/>Teksts</li>
<li class="pure-u-md-6-24">5Teskts<br/>Teksts</li>
<li class="pure-u-md-6-24">6Teskts<br/>TekstTeskts<br/>TekstsTeskts<br/>TekstsTeskts<br/>Tekstss</li>
<li class="pure-u-md-6-24">7Teskts<br/>Teksts</li>
```

css

```
    ul{
    padding:0;
}
    li {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        background: #e5e5e5;
        float:left;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that works with a dynamic number of columns, or is a solution fixed at four columns ok?

Comment: yes it should be with dynamic number of columns

Comment: Is `display:flex` an option? http://jsfiddle.net/8w6ebyc4/ Edit: [support is limited](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)